# A Question Regarding TikZ Background Layer

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

In the Tik Z & PGF Manual for Version 2.10-CVS, page 120/880 there is an example to create a yellow rounded rectangular background as below:

[image]

And here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[execute at end picture=%
{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\path[fill=yellow,rounded corners]
(current bounding box.south west) rectangle
(current bounding box.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}]
\node at (0,0) {X};
\node at (2,1) {Y};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However I got an error as below:
! Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'background' could not be found
. Maybe you misspelled it?.

Do you know how to fix this? Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the manual you must to use `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`. It is written in gray color:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[execute at end picture=%
{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\path[fill=yellow,rounded corners]
(current bounding box.south west) rectangle
(current bounding box.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}]
\node at (0,0) {X};
\node at (2,1) {Y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here there is the output:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your excellent answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Aria happy to help you :-) "excellent" it is not exact ahahahah.